# Creating a host directory as a data volume in Dockerfile

Tags: docker

So when running the command for the container, I can create the host volume mount that I want with the command

```
docker run -d -P --name web -v /home/ec2-user:/home/ec2-user testing123
```

How can I turn that `/src/webapp:/opt/webapp` host directory into an argument inside of the Dockerfile? Can I use `VOLUME` to create this type of storage?

The reason I am asking is that when I tried to add it in with the arguments

```
VOLUME ["/home/ec2-user/:/home/ec2-user/" ]
```

It creates the directory inside of the container with no files except a :. How would I structure this argument to work with it?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do what you want to do because host directory is dependent to your host and your Dockerfile hence your image must not be dependent to your host. Just 'expose' a volume and use `docker run` to map your host directory to that volume.

[Note from Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume):

> The host directory is, by its nature, host-dependent. For this reason,
>   you can’t mount a host directory from Dockerfile because built images
>   should be portable. A host directory wouldn’t be available on all
>   potential hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that newer versions of Docker, won't create the directory in your host with `-v /host/path:/container/path` anymore. This was considered an anti-pattern and it was deprecated. You should manage your host file system with a different tool that gives you better guarantees.